# Monogame for Linux: monodevelop cannot find assemblies for monogame,nvorbis and opentk

Tags: linux, mono, debian, monogame

I have downloaded and installed Monogame for Linux as indicated here: http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Setting_Up_MonoGame_Linux. I already have monodevelop and mono-complete installed and ready to go, but after installing monogame, monodevelop cannot find the assemblies for Monogame.Framework, NVorbis and OpenTK. I tried searching online but I cannot find any help. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a MonoDevelop bug where the references are shown as missing when they are using special path variables, even though MonoDevelop can find them. Pressing the compile button worked!